# Showing the multi-variable limit exists using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

How does one go about the following proof?

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$  be given by $(x,y) \mapsto (x, x+y, x-y)$. Show that $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (1,0)}f(x,y)=(1, 1, 1).$$ I'm having trouble with the proof because of the different dimensions although I know we use $\left \|  \right \|$ instead of $\left |  \right |$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can someone please construct a formal proof for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|x-1|<\delta$ and $|y|<\delta$, then

\begin{align}
\|f(x,y)-(1,1,1)\|_2^2
&= (x-1)^2 + (x+y-1)^2 + (x-y-1)^2\\
&\le (x-1)^2 + (|x-1|+|y|)^2 + (|x-1|+|y|)^2\\
&\le 9\delta^2.
\end{align}

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow the 2 '2's at the end of the norm. I think this is the very step that if confusing me. Could please elaborate on this?

Comment: @HKT If you are only familiar with the Euclidean norm, then ignore the subscript; it is the same as your $\| \cdot \|$. The superscript $2$ is just an exponent. That is, $\|(x,y,z)\|_2^2 = \|(x,y,z)\|^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help, I get it now. And I think it's a $3\delta^2$ that we end up with instead of $9\delta^2$. So we take $\delta=\epsilon/\sqrt{3}$.